# Elegant way to reduce list by factor of 2 by combining neighboring elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, reduce

I have a list of numbers (sorted ascending) and I want to halve the list several times, and combine neighbors, something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ts-node
'use strict';

const goFrom_131072_to_1024 = (v: number[]) => {

  let ret = [...v].sort();

  const reduceByHalf = (v: any[]) => {
    return v.reduce((a,b,currentIndex) => {
      
      if(currentIndex % 2 !== 0){
         return [a[0],b]
      }
      
      a[0].push((a[1] + b)/2); // take average of 2 neighbors
      return [a[0], null];

    },[[], null]);
  };

  while(ret.length > 1024){
    console.log(ret.length);
    ret = reduceByHalf(v)[0];
  }

  return ret;
}

console.log(
  goFrom_131072_to_1024(
    new Array(131072).fill(null).map((v,i) => i)
  )
);
```

when I run it (with ts-node), gets stuck at `65536`, not really sure why. There is also one potential bug where if the list had a length that's an odd number, the last element would get lost (but it's an even numbered length so fine for now). Is there a more elegant way to do this?

(Ultimately the reason I am doing this is that the numbers in the list represent a histogram (probability distribution) and I want to represent the population with a smaller sample. Combining (in this case, averaging) neighbors might be a relatively crude  way to do this, will take advice on better ways.)

Comment: It looks like you look for a Moving Average (SMA, WMA, EMA, ...) algorithm? https://github.com/peterthoeny/moving-average-js

Comment: @PeterThoeny yes more or less, doesn't need to be fancy just needs to work, although if you look at the last part of OP, not 100% certain if a moving average is optimal

Comment: You can experiment with the interactive demo at https://peterthoeny.github.io/moving-average-js/demo.html to find the moving average algorithm that fits your use case best -- see Randomize button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you would call "elegant". Why not use a bigger average group? If you want to reduce 131072 by a factor of 128, then you could just make average of 128 numbers.

For example, if you do:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

And you want to reduce the list of 8 elements to 2 elements, you would make average groups of 4.

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Which would be:

```
[ (1+2+3+4)/4 ], [ (5+6+7+8)/4 ]
```

Which would get you the same result:

```
[ 2.5, 6.5 ]
```

So now, all you need to do is groups of 2^n and get the average of those groups.

```
function groupBy(list, t){
    let grouped = [];
    let max = Math.ceil(list.length/t);
    for(let i = 0; i < max; i++){
        grouped.push(list.slice(i*t, (i+1)*t));
    }
    return grouped;
}

function average(list){
   return list.reduce((a, b) => a + b)/list.length;
}

function reduceByFactorOfN(list, factor){
   return groupBy(list, 2**factor).map(average);
}
```

Comment: what is the ** for is that different than *?

Comment: ** is the exponentiation operator in JavaScript

Comment: ahh, yeah I use `Math.pow()` sometimes